# How to show different videos in different UICollectionView cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to show 5 different videos in five different UICollectionView cells. It sounds pretty easy to do and with 3 cells it was working fine but now somehow all the videos are in the wrong cells.

It's an ugly solution but it was working before and I can't figure out any other solution.

**Here's five different instances for AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer.**

```
    let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"summer", withExtension: "mp4")
    let theURL2 = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"newyork", withExtension: "mp4")
    let theURL3 = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"amber", withExtension: "mp4")
    let theURL4 = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"luckywhite", withExtension: "mp4")
    let theURL5 = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"coconut", withExtension: "mp4")
    avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
    avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
    avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    avPlayer.volume = 0
    avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
    object: avPlayer.currentItem)


    avPlayer2 = AVPlayer(url: theURL2!)
    avPlayerLayer2 = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer2)
    avPlayerLayer2.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    avPlayer2.volume = 0
    avPlayer2.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
    object: avPlayer2.currentItem)


    avPlayer3 = AVPlayer(url: theURL3!)
    avPlayerLayer3 = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer3)
    avPlayerLayer3.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    avPlayer3.volume = 0
    avPlayer3.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
    object: avPlayer3.currentItem)

    avPlayer4 = AVPlayer(url: theURL4!)
    avPlayerLayer4 = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer4)
    avPlayerLayer4.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    avPlayer4.volume = 0
    avPlayer4.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
    object: avPlayer4.currentItem)

    avPlayer5 = AVPlayer(url: theURL5!)
    avPlayerLayer5 = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer5)
    avPlayerLayer5.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    avPlayer5.volume = 0
    avPlayer5.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
    object: avPlayer5.currentItem)
```

And here I put the videos into the cells.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
            self.avPlayerLayer.frame = cell.image.layer.bounds
            cell.image.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        case 1:
            self.avPlayerLayer2.frame = cell.image.layer.bounds
            cell.image.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer2, at: 0)

        case 2:
            self.avPlayerLayer3.frame = cell.image.layer.bounds
            cell.image.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer3, at: 0)

        case 3:
            self.avPlayerLayer4.frame = cell.image.layer.bounds
            cell.image.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer4, at: 0)

        default:
            self.avPlayerLayer5.frame = cell.image.layer.bounds
            cell.image.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer5, at: 0)
    }
```

Why it's not working properly? I think I'm doing everything right when playing with indexPaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are reused and when you do

```
 self.avPlayerLayer4.frame = cell.image.layer.bounds
 cell.image.layer.insertSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer4, at: 0)
```

so consider cleaning it before the insert

```
  cell.image.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
      if $0 is AVPlayerLayer {
          $0.removeFromSuperlayer()
      }
   }
```

it adds the layer at the most back and show the old added layer before , instead of duplicated code you need to write a func that return a layer from a url and add it

---

Aslo consider having an array like

```
var arr = [URL]()
```

and use it instead of the switch

Comment: Is there any solution to make it work? Or it's impossible?

Comment: It's working like charm. I hope it will work fine with 10-15 different videos. Thank you so much, sir!